# What HTTP error should I return if client sends incorrect type of data to REST API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, web, backend

Say I have a page that requests the user to send `ID`, and `ID` should be an `Integer`. If the user send an alphanumerical (or anything that doesn't fit `Integer` format), should I return `400 - Bad Request` or `406 - Not Acceptable`?

Comment: Take a look at e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors to see what these responses mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

406 would be correct if the request had an unsupported media type.

422 might be what you're looking for; see https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#STATUS_422.

Answer (score 1):

Since REST API are request-based, `400 - Bad request` seems more explicit and adapted to such a case.